# Install rails 2.3.5 mac os 10.6 (snow leopard)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, macos, rubygems

My website is developed with ruby on rails 2.0.2.
So I want to update this version to 2.3.5.

Unfortunately, the new rails version doesn't include mysql so I install the mysql gem like this tutorial said => [install rails](http://hivelogic.com/articles/ruby-rails-mongrel-mysql-osx)

But and it's my problem, when I launch my server (webrick), mysql crash (segmentation fault).
I don't find why mysql crash and I can't continue to develop my website.

Someone can help me ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, with rails 2.3, application.rb is renamed application_crontroller.rb.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem this guide solved it for me:

http://norbauer.com/notebooks/code/notes/snow-leopard-upgrading-for-rails-developers

Given:

```
$ sudo mv /usr/local/mysql/data /usr/local/mysql/data.default
$ sudo mv /usr/local/mysql-oldversion/data /usr/local/mysql/data
$ sudo gem uninstall mysql
$ sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
$ sudo gem pristine --all
```

Let us know if it helps.